# change height only first ul li

Tags: html, css

i have navbar from ul li ...

i want change height size only for some li

my code is:

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li>category
    <ul>
      <li>mobile
        <ul>
          <li>iphone
            <ul>
              <li>11</li>
              <li>12</li>
              <li>13</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>samsung
            <ul>
              <li>note 9</li>
              <li>note 10</li>
              <li>note 11</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>nokia
            <ul>
              <li>c1</li>
              <li>c2</li>
              <li>c3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>tablet</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>search</li>
  <li>article</li>
</ul>

</ul>
```

i want change height size only for mobile and tablet li not another li from other ul

Comment: You could just add a class with the height.

Comment: @SecretTimes thanks, but i don't want use class i want use css code for ul#main-menu, because i'm generating this codes in server side...

Comment: use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` selector...

Comment: Research 'media queries', which applies CSS to different sizes of devices.

Comment: @wazz what does your comment have to do with the question? He does not want to apply design changes for certain devices but for the list items

Comment: Look at the sentence under the snippet...

Comment: @tacoshy thanks, is possible show me example ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What "height size" are you referring to?

Comment: @wazz those are names of list items not device names... ( look at the content of the lsit)

Comment: Ahh.....bloody hell

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to change the height of mobile and tablet li without adding a class in li, i want change them with (like): ul#main-menu li ul:first-of-type li{height:100px;border:1px solid #aeaeae;}

Comment: `#main-menu > ul > li { ... }` Have a look at the different **[CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)** you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#main-menu > li:first-of-type > ul:first-of-type > li
```

You first select the first direct child li in the main-menu then its first direct child ul then all its direct child lis.

Note: 100px is very small for the amount of text to be included in the lis so 300px is used in this snippet.

```css
#main-menu > li:first-of-type > ul:first-of-type > li {
 height:300px;
 border:1px solid #aeaeae;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
  <li>category
    <ul>
      <li>mobile
        <ul>
          <li>iphone
            <ul>
              <li>11</li>
              <li>12</li>
              <li>13</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>samsung
            <ul>
              <li>note 9</li>
              <li>note 10</li>
              <li>note 11</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>nokia
            <ul>
              <li>c1</li>
              <li>c2</li>
              <li>c3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>tablet</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>search</li>
  <li>article</li>
</ul>

</ul>
```